# Check whether for a set of $n$ lines in 3D space, no two lines intersect – without testing each pair of lines

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computational-geometry

Given a set of lines in 3D space I want to determine whether no pair of lines intersect. Trivially, this can be done by checking each pair of lines. My question is if there is a way to avoid having to check each pair.

Or, in other words: Does there exist an algorithm that tests a set of $n$ lines in 3D space for intersections in time less than $O(n^2)$?

---

*For Context:* This is motivated by line segment intersection in 2D-space, where we naively can check all pairs of line segments, but in fact, there exists [an output-sensitive algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm) that exploits the property that intersections can only occur between segments that are at some point sufficiently close to each other.

Therefore, I wonder if for a set of lines in 3D space there is no way to exploit locality in a similar way resulting in only having to test lines that are sufficiently close to each other at some point? I spent the whole day researching this topic but could not find much on it - neither any hints on possible solutions nor explanations why this is impossible. I would be happy to receive either of both.

Comment: The 2D and 3D problems are not analogous. Why don't you use line segments, rather than lines (of infinite length)?

Comment: @mr_e_man I just stated the 2D example to reference this use of locality, which is what I would like to exploit. Indeed, my follow-up question would then be the case of 3D line segments, but for a start, I thought a less restricted example would suffice. I was not able to find any approach in the literature, so my guess is that this is just not possible, but I was not able to come up with an argument for this. But if you know of an output-sensitive approach for the 3D line segment problem, I would gladly post another question s.t. you can answer it.

Comment: No, I probably know less than you do about these problems. But "infinite length" and "locality" seem at odds with each other.

Comment: I understand that one might think so, and you probably are right. What I was thinking is that e.g. if there was a way to sort the lines in a constant number of ways or group them in some way, you could somehow achieve output sensitivity. But my lack of spatial imagination does not help much here. My approach for an explanation of why it is not possible would be: For 2D line segments, locality ensures that there are only a constant number of intersections to check when sweeping the plane. In 3D, we do not have this property and could have arbitrarily many local "neighboring" lines to check.

Comment: It seems to me that if the 2-D case can be handled somehow efficiently, we might be able to make use of this by projecting onto one or more two-dimensional subspaces. Any intersection point will go to an intersection point, so eg if you project onto three subspaces in general position this probably gives you some useful information. But in this case the number of crossings ($k$ in your link) is $O(n^2)$, as your lines are infinite. If you instead had line segments without much expected interaction the story might be different... These are just some thoughts - I am not an expert I'm afraid.